# postgresql - DATE_PART get no such function error

Tags: sql, postgresql

tables:

```
create table product (
product_id int,
product_name varchar(50),
primary key (product_id));

insert into product values
(1, 'LC Phone'),
(2, 'LC T-Shirt'),
(3, 'LC Keychain');

create table sales (
product_id int,
period_start date,
period_end date,
average_daily_sales int);

insert into sales values
(1, '2019-01-25', '2019-02-28', 100),
(2, '2018-12-01', '2020-01-01', 10),
(3, '2019-12-01', '2020-01-31', 1);
```

Now I'd like to get the days between the period_end and period_start in table sales, I learned in postgresql I can use `DATE_PART` to calculate days different, so my sql is

```
select DATE_PART('day', period_end - period_start) as days from sales;
```

and I get this error:

```
ERROR:  function date_part(unknown, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: select DATE_PART('day', period_end - period_start) as days f...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 8
```

what's wrong with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have the date difference using

```
select period_end - period_start as days from sales;
```

is enough.

- `DATE_PART()` function looks for a `date` or a `time` value such as
  of type `date` or `timestamp` ( but not an `integer` ) as a second
  argument.

  But in your case, the subtraction `period_end - period_start` yields an **integer** which causes the error
- `DATE_PART('day',<date>)` extracts the day portion as an integer
  value

  [ `DATE_PART('day','2020-01-01::date')` -> `1` ( not `'01'`) ]

Comment: indeed, there is no need to overcomplicate.... just subtract using '-'